# Add Persistent Static Route in Centos 5

Tags: linux, networking, centos, route

What is the proper way to add a static route in Centos 5 that will persist rebooting?

I tired adding an `route-eth0` file in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` that contains a route , but after `./etc/init.d/network restart` that route is not present and there were no errors during the restart of the service.

Comment: what does route-eth0 look like?

Comment: What did you put in route-eth0?

Comment: There are many version of Centos 5.....Is this a problem in Centos 5.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's indeed the right place to add it (if the route is actually reachable via eth0), as documented here:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html

Comment: Wrong interface, so the destination gateway was not reachable via that interface.